# Python Menu is not working- stopped at ELIF

Tags: python, python-3.x

When i run my code, i have an error at ELIF. Whenever I try submitting this, it gives me an invalid syntax error at the elif. I have read different threads about this, but those had elif indented too far.

My current code :

```
from collections import Counter 
print ("   M A I N - M E N U")
print ("1.People")
print ("2.Name")
print ("3. Country")
print ("4. Continent")
opt = int(input("Enter option: "))
if opt ==1:
  print ("People")
from collections import Counter 
counterY = Counter()
with open('json.txt') as f:
        for i in range(0,2):
            next(f)
        for line in f:
            splits = line.split(';')
            people = int(splits[3])
            counter1[name] += people
for name, pop_sum in counter1.most_common():
    print(Name, ":", pop_sum)
elif opt == 2:
  from collections import Counter 
counterx = Counter()
with open("json.txt") as f:
    for i in range(0,2):
            next(f)
    for line in f:
        splits = line.split(';')
        change = float(splits[6])
        country = splits[1].strip()
        counter2[country] += change      
#Percentage Change By Countries"
print()
print ("Countries"):
    print(country)
```

Comment: Is there a way to link back to the menu once the user has entered an input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the indentation try:

```
import turtle
from collections import Counter 
print (30 * '-')
print ("   M A I N - M E N U")
print (30 * '-')
print ("1.Total Populations of the different continents")
print ("2.Percentage Change(%) for different countries")
print ("3. Continent with the lowest Population")
print ("4. Choose a country")
print (30 * '-')
opt = int(input("Enter option: "))
if opt ==1:
    print ("Continents Sorted By Population")
    from collections import Counter 
    counter1 = Counter()
    with open('demo.txt') as f:
        for i in range(0,2):
            next(f)
        for line in f:
            splits = line.split(';')
            population = int(splits[3])
            continent = splits[-1].strip()
            counter1[continent] += population
        # Print continents sorted by population
        for continent, pop_sum in counter1.most_common():
            print(continent, ":", pop_sum)
elif opt == 2:
    from collections import Counter
    counter2 = Counter()
    with open("demo.txt") as f:
        for i in range(0,2):
            next(f)
        for line in f:
            splits = line.split(';')
            change = float(splits[6])
            country = splits[1].strip()
            counter2[country] += change      
    #Percentage Change By Countries"
    print()
    print ("Percentage Change By Countries")
    for country, change_sum in counter2.most_common():
        print(country, change_sum,"%")
elif opt==3:
    #Finding continent with lowest population
    counter3 = Counter()
    with open("demo.txt") as f:
        for i in range(0,2):
            next(f)
        for line in f:
            counter3[continent] += population
    for continent, pop_total in counter3.most_common():
        print()
        print("Continent with the Lowest Population")
        print(continent,":", pop_sum)
        print()
else:
    def file_search():
        userInput = input('Enter a country: ').lower()
        result = []
        with open("demo.txt", 'r') as f:
            for x in f:
                if userInput in x.lower():
                    result.append(x.split(';'))
        for s in result:
            print(s[1] + " \nCountry Rank: "+ s[0]+ " \n2019 population: " + s[3] + "\nPopulation change(%)"+s[6]+"\nContinent:  "+ s[7])
    file_search()
```

Comment: Thanks ! [extra help] Is there a way to link back to the menu once the user has entered an input?

Comment: @PaviThira I would recommended you to ask another question and clarify what you need exactly, and also that would make more users activate to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Python is sensitive to indents once you unindent and do not use an elif or else statement, it will assume that you are finished with the if statement.

So, the compiler is confused when it reaches elif, as it does not see an if statement associated with it. So you will have to indent all the lines between the if statement and your elif statement to fix the error and indent all the lines between successive elif statements